# Problem about Show Data Filter By Date In MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table **Order**:

```
id    total_amount       date_order 
1        12.000          2018-09-01
2        10.000          2018-09-01
3         5.000          2018-09-03
4         2.000          2018-09-05
```

I have query SUM data group by date:

```
select SUM(total_amount) as 'total', DATE(date_order) as 'date'
from Order
where date_order >= '2018-09-01' and date_order <= '2018-09-06'
group by (date_order)
```

It shows:

```
   total           date       
  22.000        2018-09-01      
   5.000        2018-09-03   
   2.000        2018-09-05
```

Because data in **2018-09-02** and **2018-09-04** have no data so It's not show in result. But I want query to show table with expect result:

```
   total           date       
  22.000        2018-09-01    
       0        2018-09-02      
   5.000        2018-09-03
       0        2018-09-04   
   2.000        2018-09-05
```

Every can help me write query to show like expect result ?

Comment: outer join a calendar help table

Comment: that's not how group by works. It can't group on things which don't exist. How should it know what the missing values would be? To get what you want, you need to create a separate table with all the possible dates in it, and join to that, as mentioned above. SQL has no inherent understanding of calendars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generate date and join with ordere table

```
    select SUM(O.total_amount) as total, DATE(gen_date) as oreder_date
        from    
        (
         select * from 
            (select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) gen_date from
             (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
             (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
             (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
             (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
             (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
            where gen_date between '2018-09-01' and '2018-09-30'
        ) as t1 left join `Order` O on t1.gen_date= DATE(O.date_order)

where gen_date >= '2018-09-01' and gen_date <= '2018-09-06'
         group by oreder_date
```

Answer (score 2):

Create another table to join on.

It could be a table of dates, such as all date from 2000-01-01 until 2099-12-31...

```
SELECT
  dt.`date`,
  SUM(total_amount) as `total`
FROM
  yourDatesTable     AS dt
LEFT JOIN
  Order              AS o
    ON  o.`date_order` = dt.`date`
WHERE
      dt.`date` >= '2018-09-01'
  AND dt.`date` <  '2018-09-08'
GROUP BY
  dt.`date`
ORDER BY
  dt.`date`
```

Or it could be a numbers table with values from -1023 to +1024 *(or some other useful range)*...

```
SELECT
  n.id,
  '2018-09-01' + INTERVAL n.id DAYS,
  SUM(total_amount) as `total`
FROM
  yourNumbersTable   AS n
LEFT JOIN
  Order              AS o
    ON  o.`date_order` = '2018-09-01' + INTERVAL n.id DAYS
WHERE
      n.id >= 0
  AND n.id <  8
GROUP BY
  n.id
ORDER BY
  n.id
```